# error bool has no attribute shift, shift doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  the dataframe:

```
data = {'in_id': ['28076','28076','28076','28076'],
'name': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],  
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data , columns = ['in_id','name'])
```

[image]

So, i try to run `df.groupby('in_id').apply(lambda x: x[(x.name=='four').shift(-1).fillna(False)])`
but i get an error 'bool' object has no attribute 'shift'

How do i can to run it without getting an error?
Can anyone see the problem

Output dataframe

[image]

Comment: is the output dataframe your intended output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out=df[df['name'].eq('four').shift(-1,fill_value=False)]
```

**OR**(If there is particular reason of using `groupby()`)

```
out=(df.groupby('in_id')['name']
   .agg(lambda x: x[x.eq('four').shift(-1,fill_value=False)])
   .reset_index())
#you can also use apply() in place of agg() method
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output